# ProxyPass URL Rules?

Tags: django, apache, proxypass

I have a website `http://foo.com` running on Apache port 80 which I would like to redirect to a Django app on port 8000.  However, I have one folder, `foo.com/wiki` which I would not like to redirect and have it point to my wiki folder in my regular `/var/www directory`.  In my httpd.conf file I have:

```
...
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/project/wsgi.py

ProxyPass /wiki !

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
```

Which seems to lead `foo.com/wiki` nowhere (You don't have permission to access /wiki/ on this server).  I've heard of `ProxyPassMatch` on another question and also tried

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(wiki/*) http://localhost:8000/

ProxyPassReverse ^/(wiki/*) http://localhost:8000/
```

Which also didn't work for me.

Comment: If you remove Proxy things, does the wiki/url works? If you still have the permission problem then fix it (DocumentRoot, user rights, etc). Then restablish Proxy things, which may be completly unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Yes, if I remove all the proxy lines I can access foo.com and foo.com/wiki

Answer (score 0):

I do not have anything to test that. But I think it may be related to the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive. You are excluding /wiki from proxy rewriting but not from the WSGIScriptAlias thing.

You could maybe try something like that:

```
<Location /wiki>
  RemoveHandler wsgi-script
  Options -ExecCGI
</Location>
```

Or instead of use `WSGIScriptAliasMatch` and exclude the wiki sub-url in the regex.